# How to remove specific time-range data using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataset `df` looks like this:

```
time                    Open
2017-01-01 00:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-01 01:00:00     5.2180
2017-01-01 02:00:00     5.2128
...., ....
2017-12-31 23:00:00     5.7388
```

This is an `hourly` dataset.

I want to remove any data between `10 PM Friday` to `10 AM Sunday`

**What did I do?**

- I am able to remove the entire day like this:

  ```
  df = df[df['time'].dt.dayofweek != 5] # Removes Saturday
  ```
- But I want to remove couple of hours of `Friday` and `Sunday` aswell.

How do I do this?

Comment: From your last question, it seems like an `xy` problem. Your extended question can be solved without breaking into the two small pieces.

Comment: What does `xy` problem mean? Can you help solve the other question? It does not seem to work.

Comment: it should work with `copy()`.

Comment: Look at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for an explanation of `xy` problem.

Comment: what does `copy()` do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just write your conditions one by one

```
s1=df['time'].dt.dayofweek == 5
s2=(df['time'].dt.dayofweek == 4)&(df.time.dt.hour>20)
s3=(df['time'].dt.dayofweek == 6)&(df.time.dt.hour<10)
df=df[~(s1|s2|s3)]
```

Comment: This works, but I go this message. `UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index. after removing the cwd from sys.path.` What does this mean and do we need to fix it?

Comment: @flossf try `df=df[~(s1|s2|s3)].copy()`?

Comment: what does `.copy()` do? I tried and it still does not work.

Comment: @floss that is just a warning ... they match the index .